# Angular - Redirect to index.html

Tags: angular, routes, angular-router

I have Angular 7 application which I want to redirect to login page (but show /index.html instead of /login in the URL) after a timeout.

Throughout the application, I do not want to display the relative paths in the URL and just show /index.html on redirection of all pages (due to the design of the application).

So, I'm using `skipLocationChange: true` for this.

app.routing.ts:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent },
  {
    path: 'dashBoard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
      { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent },
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' },
];
```

I redirect to ProfileComponent from Login component using:

```
this.router.navigate(['dashBoard/profile'], { skipLocationChange: true })
```

In the Profile and Account component, after a timer expires, I'm doing:

```
this.router.navigate(['/login'], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

This makes the application redirect to login page but shows /dashBoard/profile in the URL.

So, first, why did the URL change to /dashBoard/profile when I had mentioned skipLocationChange: true ?

Then I tried:

```
this.router.navigate(['/index.html'], { replaceUrl: true });
```

This makes the application redirect to login page but shows /login in the URL.

I want to show /index.html in the URL after redirection from /dashBoard/profile. How can I do this?